# Play 2.0.2-RC2: Less compiler not working for me (Twitter Bootstrap)

Tags: less, playframework-2.0

## Goal

My goal is to to get Twitter Bootstrap to worth with my Play 2.x scala project. Because i can't get it to wrok i decided to start an empty project to see if i can get the hang of 'less'. Now thats where i'm stuck, as i can't seem to get 'less' to compile/do anything!

### Simple reproduction in an empty project

- Downloaded http://www.playframework.org/download play-2.0.2-RC2.zip and extracted that to my debian linux box. (Why play-2.0.2-RC2? Because the 'less' version in there is compatible with the latest twitter bootstrap as mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/play-framework/less$20doesnt$20work/play-framework/PjBzAQm65Sw/tSeZkq7yKeMJ).)
- Created a new play project `play new zzz` (zzz=name of the test project).
- Went to `zzz/public/stylesheets` and added a file named `q.less` (its content is the first example on this page http://lesscss.org/, simple variable name usage).
- Because i'm testing a lot i each time type: `play clean-all` in the commandline before each new test/Build.scala/etc file change.
- Started `play` and typed:

  - `reload` (don't really know why)
  - `compile` (as per: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/AssetsLess)
  - (*) See below
  - i ctrl+d'ed out of play and typed: `find . -name *.css` and it doesn't show me my 'q.css' anywhere.

#### The plot thickens

Now after reading a [a message on google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/play-framework/nilanjan$20play$20compile/play-framework/Qtb3XTn2nJ8/6ZxsXQe3IA8J) i spotted two things:

1. He hinted the less compiler in Build.scala to only build certain files. Which isn't a problem for my empty 'zzz' test project (as it doesnt have partial twitter bootstrap less files), but i added these lines nevertheless to test: `lessEntryPoints <<= baseDirectory(_ / "app" / "assets" / "stylesheets" ** "q.less")`.

   - Note: if i type `play-less-entry-points` in the play console i get two empty lines just stating '[info]' ... nothing more. Something wrong there?
2. He (and someone else) mentioned the play commands `play-copy-assets` and `copy-resources`. I entered these commands at the above replication step at '(*)'. Same result, no css files.

### Edit: my 'target' directory listing

My target directory listing after testing the above, and before i 'reset' it with a `play clean-all` in the command line looks like this:

```
cache  classes  classes_managed  src_managed
```

It doesn't have the mentioned 'resource_managed' directory. Is there a log / verbose mode i can see if the less compilere is called at all. Perhaps there is a less syntax error in my test file? I just dont know anymore :).

### Perhaps related, but not important for my question?

Perhaps related and might help me understand it ... but: [The official 'site'](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Tips) mentions the use of a double '**' in the `lessEntryPoints` lines. [Here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436815/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-2-with-play-framework-2-0) uses one '*' and [the message on google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/play-framework/nilanjan$20play$20compile/play-framework/Qtb3XTn2nJ8/6ZxsXQe3IA8J) doesn't even use it. How does that work?

## My question

I'd like to understand what i'm doing 'wrong' here. With that knowledge i'm sure i'm able to get twitter bootstrap into my play project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to be sure, make sure that your *.less files are located under the "**app**/assets/..." folder and not in your "public" folder.

Only the files located under the "app" (and "conf") folder(s) are compiled.

Comment: I just did a quick test and indeed this was the case :(. Thanks for the tip! ... once i'm home i'm gonna check if i could have read this in the documentation or not ... because ... damn i feel stupid :).