# Twitter Bootstrap in Play applications

Tags: scala, twitter-bootstrap, playframework-2.2

I'm going to involve Twitter Bootstrap in my Play project. I found some articles about it but, as I understood, there is no a standard approach.

So what's the most standard way of working with Twitter Bootstrap in Play applications?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [webjars](http://www.webjars.org/) for that. First you have to add `bootstrap` to dependencies eg. in `project/dependencies.scala`:

```
import sbt._
object Dependencies {
  val bootstrapVersion = "(2.3.2,)"
...
  val bootstrap = "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % bootstrapVersion
...
  val myDependencies = Seq(..., bootstrap, ...)
}
```

The value of the `bootstrapVersion` tells `sbt` to update to the latest bleeding-edge `bootstrap`. You can also fix it to a specific version you desire. Then use it in the main `build.sbt`:

```
import Dependencies._

...

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(cache) ++ myDependencies

play.Project.playScalaSettings

...
```

Then in the main layout file (like `app/views/main.scala.html`)

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.locate("bootstrap.min.js"))'></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.locate("bootstrap.min.css"))">
```

Then in the `app/assets/stylesheets` you can put only modifications of the `bootstrap` styles.

The advantage of the above is that you set the `bootstrap` (or any other `webjar`) version in exactly one place.

See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436815/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-2-with-play-framework-2-x).

Comment: the question is not about what I could use but what I should use.

Comment: @Alex so would it be better if I wrote 'you should use...' in the first sentence? I can do that for you if you wish. Normally I don't do that because I respect other people's ability to think for themselves, and choosing the right solution best suited for their usage.

Comment: by should use I mean a library which is supposed to be standard.

Comment: @Alex webjars are pushed forward by James Ward, a Developer Advocate at TypeSafe. Quite a lot project started to use it. But the choice is still yours.

Comment: what's the difference between your approach and biesior's one?

Comment: @Alex you don't have to manually place files in the `public` directory, and version upgrade can happen automatically or is as simple as changing one number in one file. On the other hand you can't easily modify the `bootstrap` files, but I don't think that's a good idea, anyway.

Comment: `value WebJarAssets is not a member of object controllers.routes`

Answer (score 0):

There is standard approach:

Just unzip the Bootstrap in your `public` folder, you don't need to move its parts (JS, styles, images) to Play's folders just leave them in the original structure and at the end include it in your layout with common `routes.Assets.at(path)` method.

There are some common helpers allowing you to build forms with Bootstrap (2.x) elements, anyway you can also write your own if these built-in doesn't satisfy you. Both approaches are described [in the helpers documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaFormHelpers)

Comment: `routes.Assets.at(path)` - where do I write this and what's "path"?

Comment: It's just path to your asset (according to your `public` dir): `<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")"></script>` see in the doc: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaTemplateUseCases

Comment: why jquery? where do I write this? Could you give me the exact code?

Comment: sorry, but I asked 3 questions.