# Play 2.2.1 - twitter bootstrap 3 less setup

Tags: configuration, playframework-2.0, less, twitter-bootstrap-3

For a new project I want to use Play 2.2.1 (java) and Twitter bootstrap 3 (less).

I've followed the instructions as posted here: [Link to other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436815/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-2-with-play-framework-2-x)
But these seem to be specific for play 2.1.x versions. I get stuck when to tell Play not to compile each less file, but only bootstrap.less 
How should I configure this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can still use the pre 2.2.x way to configure your project with the `project/Build.scala` file ([2.2.x Release Notes - sbt 0.13 support](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Highlights22)), but I think that is only possible if you remove the new `build.sbt` file.

On the play mailing list was discussed another solution which works with the `build.sbt`file ([Setting lessEntryPoints in build.sbt](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/MVJXk1_ivqA)).

```
play.Keys.lessEntryPoints <<= baseDirectory { base =>
   (base / "app" / "assets" / "stylesheets" / "bootstrap" * "bootstrap.less") +++
   (base / "app" / "assets" / "stylesheets" / "bootstrap" * "responsive.less") +++
   (base / "app" / "assets" / "stylesheets" * "*.less")
}
```

I tested it in a little sample project and it works ([Sample project with play 2.2.1 and Bootstrap 3.1.0 on github](https://github.com/tilmanpotthof/play-2.2.1-boostrap)).